# RowLimit for GetListItems

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to retrieve data with all columns from a large SharePoint list (57000+ items and increasing everyday) using webservice.

The problem that I face is that; in the below code, I have heard that the ndRowLimit's recommended value is 5000. When I am setting 57000, I am getting operation timed out.

```
XmlNode ndListItems = listService.GetListItems(ListName, null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, ndRowLimit, ndQueryOptions, null);
```

Does anyone know any method using which I can get all the list items and all the columns?

Comment: Have you looked into paging your data? Or if you are needing it for some programmatic purpose, have you checked your web.config settings for your web service? You may want to check these settings on your `bindingConfiguration` for your endpoint. These attributes `maxBufferSize
          maxReceivedMessageSize` allow you to specify larger sizes for receiving data. Try specifying a larger download size. Note that it is in bytes. I'm not familiar with Sharepoint, so forgive me if I'm waaaaay off.

Comment: Hi @MightyLampshade, thanks for your comment! I tried to find something for paging the data. Will that bring all the rows into the XML file? Would you have any example please?

Comment: Firstly are you using this data in something like a gridview? Or are you using it for some programmatic function? If you are wanting to display this data to a user, 57000 rows is far too much for someone to read.

Comment: I am not using this data as an input to a programmatic function. I am trying to get this list back in an xml format with all the rows to insert into a SQL table (which will be done outside this solution). So the end result would just be an xml file with everything the list has to offer.

Comment: Ah okay. Did you try the web.config stuff I put earlier? I'm assuming you are using an ASP.NET web application/MVC application? Are you sure the webservice you are requesting the data from allows that amount of data to be transferred across? Can you take a look at the webservice config and see if there is a limit to the download size?

Comment: Page your data and get it as batches or use a connector built to handle such amounts of data, in example http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, you can increase the connection time-out setting, follow these steps.

Note By default, the IIS connection time-out setting is 120 seconds.

You can update it via IIS Manager.
Click the Web Site and then the Connection Timeout is under Advanced Settings.

You may run into a further timeout issue which is controlled in the web.config - (always backing that up).  But the property that has a default timeout of 110 seconds is under `<system.web>`

This sets the timeout to 10 minutes.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="6000" maxRequestLength="51200" />
```

Finally, after you beat the timeout issue, you'll probably need to (temporarily) adjust the throttling of results at that list or through Central Administration.  Here's a great article on the in's and out's of that: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/27/working-with-large-lists-in-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling.aspx